# How to match these strings using preg_match

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match('/"\'<>&/', 'misiek"')
```

Why does not it work ?

Comment: <joke>It does work. Every single line of code works exactly the way you wrote it. :D </joke> Seriously, we don't even know what is the line of code supposed to do. What is its output upon running it? What do you want it to be?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments - it does exactly what you told it to do. In your case, you simply check if the string you provide contains the exact substring: "\'<>& anywhere.

So with your pattern, the following strings would result in a match:

- **"'<>&**
- **LOREM "'<>& IPSUM**

Since both of these include the pattern you searched for. However, **LO"R'EM<>IPS&UM** would not return a match, because you are not checking for the individual characters, only the complete pattern.

If you change your pattern to:

```
/["\'<>&]/
```

You instead look for a list of characters. This will return true if any of the characters wrapped in brackets are found.

- **misiek** - would in this case not match
- **LO"R'EM<>IPS&UM** - would match
- **mis&iek** - would match

You can test your regex patterns as well as build them on this site:

https://regex101.com

There you'll also find the available modifiers you can use and how / why to use them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am *guessing*: could it be that you want to match a string *containing at least one of the characters* listed in your regular expression? In that case you should do the following:

```
$res=preg_match('/["\'<>&]/' , 'misiek"');
```

And the result should be positive  (`$res===1`), see here:
 http://rextester.com/KYNGYI23753

Comment: Would return 0 in this case, though? :-)

Comment: The return value is `1`, see the link I added above.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the ” att the end of misiek. ^^ All is well. :)